# Pandas - add column headers to row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrame with columns such as `columnA`, `columnB`, `columnC`, `columnD`...`columnX`.

For all the rows in these columns, I want to prefix the row values with the column name itself.

For `columnA`, for example:

columnA 4
columnA 10
columnA 14

For `columnE`, for example:

columnE Apple
columnE Banana
columnE Orange

**What's the best way to do this for many (~30) columns?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
column_subset = ['columnA', 'columnB', 'columnC', 'columnD',
           'columnE']

for header in column_subset:
    df[header] = header + df[header]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following DataFrame. Use `apply` would be simple:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.ones((5,3)),
    columns = ['a','b','c']
)

print(df.apply(lambda col: col.name +" "+ col.astype(str) ))


Out[8]: 
      a     b     c
0  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
1  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
2  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
3  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
4  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try broadcasting:

```
df.columns.values[None,:] + ' ' + df.astype(str)
```

Output for data frame from snowneji:

```
       a      b      c
0  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
1  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
2  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
3  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
4  a 1.0  b 1.0  c 1.0
```